# Why most iOS apps crashed without an alert window

Tags: ios, user-experience

Most iOS Apps crashed without any reason or explanation window. They just disappeared.

But Mac Apps always have a explanation window to let the user know what happened.

Why we don't show a alert window when iOS App crash? Is there any reason for User Experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash window that you can see on Mac OS is presented by the system itself, not by the app.
For iOS, Apple chose not to display any message. This is their choice and we can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

actually, most of crash have very long log (which hard to be seen on small mobile device's screen). so I think they decide to ignore the alert (or in android case, just showing force close message) and leave the rest at the console log. You can use iPhone Configuration Utility to check that log.