# Showing a popup message when iOS app stops working

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, user-interface

This question is related to

[Why most iOS apps crashed without an alert window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474885/why-most-ios-apps-crashed-without-an-alert-window/32312101)

I am leading a team of software developers and we are developing a mobile App which is presently targeted on both iOS and Android mobile devices. In Android, when the App is not responding, a popup message is displayed (Refer screen shot in the URL below).

http://postimg.org/image/4hr48vf69/

The Android developer informed me that it is a built in feature of Android and he did not write any code to show this message. Our iOS developer told us that when an iOS App is not responding, iOS does not display any message; iOS closes the App and control goes directly back to the home screen of the phone. Also he does not know how to trap that notification to show a similar popup message. We want to maintain consistency of functionality between Android and iOS Apps. Could somebody help me in knowing how this can be done for iOS.

Thanks for your help.

Mahesh

---

{Edited on 01-September-2015 : Added below text based on answers given}

I checked out the Android Hyderabad RTC App (available in Google Playstore) and when it crashes, the popup has two buttons "Report" and "OK"

When "OK" is clicked, the popup closes and control goes back to the screen which was displayed when the Android App crashed. When "Report" is clicked, the App opens mail screen where the user can optionally enter comments and click Send ">" button at top right of the screen.

In the mail screen when "System Information" is clicked, a report is shown which has - Package name, version, process name, Time, Build ID, Phone model and brand, System log, Event log, Exception class name, Source file and class name, method name, Full Stack trace etc. When user clicks send on the mail screen, the report is sent and a popup message "Thank you Your feedback has been sent" is displayed for about 5 to 8 seconds and then the popup automatically closes.

We want to implement this kind of functionality in our Apps both Android and iOS.

Since I am unable to add multiple URLs to this edit, I am posting a Gallery with the screen shots.

http://postimg.org/gallery/3d6vrva1a/

Thanks for your help ~ Mahesh

Comment: You wont have enough time for UI updation if you app crashes. But you can show an alert on next session. You can check this by using `stop()` function.

Comment: Why don't you just try to avoid the **App not responding** situation

Comment: can't we sleep the App to update the UI

avoiding App not responding is the best, but if App crashes we want to show message to user

Comment: No we cant. Because iOS don't wait. System end up everything when the log (crash report) is ready. Even android applications doesn't have that feature , it is android system who pop up a window and ask if user want to give time to application and sometime application recover the state (if state is not responding) otherwise it just show app crashes message. Apple chose not to display pop up

Comment: Well apple has the feature all crash reports will automatically uploaded to `itunes connect` if user allowed. You can recover the state of application by making your own system. `NSCoding` will help you here. It will be like some photo editing application where you create multiple layers of effects and save the edit. when you open the edit next time all layers are there as you created before.

Comment: In Hyderabad RTC App, there is a "Report" button (Refer screen shot below)

http://postimg.org/image/n7pem27ul/

My Android developer has said that he can add "Report" button to our Android App. My iOS developer is looking for help to build a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is a crash message that is generated by android OS. There is no such system message generated in iOS. So, You won't get this type of any message in iOS. To prevent this and also to avoid rejection from apple store you must have to check that where the application is crashing and find a proper solution for that.

Comment: In our iOS developer's mobile iPhone device, we are checking where the application is crashing and trying to find a proper solution for that. But the problem is if the iOS App crashes on an end user's iPhone, we want to give the user the option to easily report the problem to us. Also we want the user to know that the App crashed instead of suddenly the home screen is displayed - Mahesh

Comment: For that you can go through a solution by logging app activities into a text file and retrieve that file from where you have saved. By that you can analyse that where the app crashes. Please note that There is no way to give pop-up when app crashes in iOS AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Apple choose not to display any message and the reason could be that users don't have to know what goes wrong. So basically you can't do anything much about it. However, that should be its developers to analyse and fix it from their end by checking crash logs in Xcode or crash reporting tool from your backend.

Comment: Apple choose not to display any message - I am surprised. I thought it was normal for any system to give the programmer choice of deciding how to handle exceptions / errors. 

"users don't have to know what goes wrong" Users don't have to know, but if users are given an easy method to report it, it would be helpful to our developers for maintenance and debugging / recreating the problem.

In Hyderabad RTC Android App, there is a "Report" button (Refer screen shot below)

http://postimg.org/image/n7pem27ul/

We want to add similar functionality - Mahesh

Comment: Apple may think this should be developers' tasks totally but I can understand how frustrated you are. At this point I believe we can't do much about it.